# How Firebase FCM registration token generation works internally?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I want to know how the firebase FCM registration token is getting generated? is it generated by firebase SDK or by android OS?

How does the firebase FCM registration token is getting generated? is it generated by firebase SDK or by android OS?